# Usage of WebView in Typescript template of react native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to use WebView in the react native boilerplate (template: typescript).
I am using `WebView` from `react-native-webview` library.

```
    /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * Generated with the TypeScript template
 * https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript
 *
 * @format
 */

import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const App = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'} />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        <Header />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          }}>
          <WebView
            source={{
              uri: 'https://www.google.com/',
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export default App;
```

But it is showing

```
(alias) class WebView<P = {}>
import WebView
JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.ts(2607)
'WebView' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'WebView<{}>' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'WebView<{}>' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.ts(2786)
```

How can I workaround this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';
    
export default class MyInlineWeb extends Component {
  public render() {
    return <WebView originWhitelist={['*']} source={{ html: '<h1>Hello world</h1>' }}/>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation as to how this solves the issue?